# New systemd service for all targets

Tags: systemd

I have added new service in systemd as shown below.

> [Unit]
>   Description=Server Application
>
> [Service]
>   ExecStart=/usr/bin/server

How to make this service to run for all the available targets.

Answer (score 0):

You would need a `[Install]` section.

```
[Install]
WantedBy=basic.target
```

`basic.target` would be used for all other targets except I think `shutdown` and/or `reboot` targets.

You also need to enable your `service`.

```
$ systemctl enable my-awesome.service
```

Answer (score 0):

No such thing as "all available targets" unless you have a very specific usecase you have not told us your service should be

> WantedBy=multi-user.target